# Wordpress Query by Category using Post Slug

Tags: wp-query

I am trying to query some posts by the category slug (and parent post category slug)

I can get the slug using

```
<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>
```

or

```
<?php $post_data = get_post($post->post_parent);
$parent_slug = $post_data->post_name;
echo $parent_slug; ?>
```

I would like to insert that into the query below:

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type' => 'offers',
'category_name' => 'PAGE-SLUG-event'
)); ?>
```

So effectively I am trying to do this, which doesn't obviously work.

```
 <?php $query = new WP_Query(array(
 'post_type' => 'offers',
 'category_name' => '<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>-event'
 )); ?>
```

Comment: `'category_name' => $post->post_name . '-event'` is the correct way to pass that slug appended with `-event`.

Answer (score 0):

function namefunctions(){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'CPT',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    $recetax = new wp_query($args);
    while ( $recetax->have_posts()): $recetax->the_post(); ?>

```
/* your content of ctp*/

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();
```

}